# Como fazer multiplos temas para um site?

Tags: css

Como funciona os múltiplos temas em um site?

Eu tenho

```
themeRED.css e themeBlue.css
```

tenho que gravar no banco o local do css?
ou existe forma mais fácil ?

Comment: Como você vai querer que seja mostrado o `themeRED.css` ou `themeBlue.css`, qual configuração, que vai ser responsável por saber qual tema utilizar. Exemplo: o usuário x logado tem o tema `themeRED.css` e o usuário Y tem o `themeBlue.css`, ai seria simples você decidir quem é de quem  !!! ???

Comment: Rod, dá para explicar melhor? Mudar o CSS do site "em tempo real" pode ser bem útil mas não é claro que é isso que você quer, nem como. Se explicar melhor fica mais fácil responder.

Comment: Que confusão os motivos que estão dando para fechar esta pergunta! Se é para fechar, seria por "não é claro o que você está perguntando". Porque claramente tem algo não dito aí que impede o surgimento de uma resposta "na mosca".

Comment: Eu queria entender, porque, essa questão foi suspensa, poderia ser editada e fazer um acréscimo a essa questão ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Não necessariamente vc precisa salvar em banco.

Vc pode utilizar javascript pra verificar qual o theme utilizado e carregar ele.

Aqui tem uma resposta em como carregar o CSS por Javascript:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Grava o nome do tema na banco e na hora de carregar o arquivo CSS use a string do tema do usuário para carregar o(s) css(s) com aquele tema.

Ex: "tema1"

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="temas/tema1/geral.css" />
```

Assim como o JQuery UI faz com seus diferentes temas... sem mistério. :)